# Problemas de variable indefinida

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un problema de variable indefinida, soy bastante nuevo en esto de programacion y nose donde esta el error, les dejo el codigo por si lo ven. El error supuestamenrte esta en las funciones mostrarSal() y mostrarJor()........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
//declaraciones globales
var trabajadores = [];

//Métodos del ABM
function alta(){
    var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
    var paga = obtenerPaga();
    var saldo = document.getElementById("saldo").value;
    var horas = document.getElementById("horas").value;
    var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
    

    trabajadores[trabajadores.length]= {
            Id: id,
            Nombre: nombre,
            Apellido: apellido,
            Paga : paga,
            Saldo: saldo,
            Horas: horas,
            Valor: valor;
    };
    mostrar();
    limpiar();
}

function obtenerPaga(){
    if(document.getElementById("mensual").checked)
        return "mensual";
    if(document.getElementById("jornada").checked)
        return "jornada";
}

function baja(){
    var id = parseInt(document.getElementById("id").value);
    var i = buscar(id);
    trabajadores.splice(i, 1);
    mostrar();
    limpiar();
}

function modificar(){
    var id = parseInt(document.getElementById("id").value);
    var i = buscar(id);
    trabajadores[i].Nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    trabajadores[i].Apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
    trabajadores[i].Paga = obtenerPaga();
    trabajadores[i].Saldo = document.getElementById("saldo").value;
    trabajadores[i].Horas = document.getElementById("horas").value;
    trabajadores[i].Valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
    mostrar();
}

function isNumberKey(evt) {
       var charCode= (evt.which) ? evt.which: event.KeyCode;
       return !(charCode> 31 && (charCode< 48 || charCode> 57));
}

function buscar(id){
    for(var i=0; i<trabajadores.length;i++){
        if(trabajadores[i].Id == id)
            return(i);
    }
}

function seleccionar(){
    var lista = document.getElementById("lista");
    var i = lista.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("id").value = trabajadores[i].Id;
    document.getElementById("nombre").value = trabajadores[i].Nombre;
    document.getElementById("apellido").value = trabajadores[i].Apellido;
    
    var textPaga = trabajadores[i].Paga;
    if(textPaga == "mensual")
        document.getElementById("mensual").checked = true;
    if(textPaga == "jornada")
        document.getElementById("jornada").checked = true;
    
    document.getElementById("saldo").value = trabajadores[i].Saldo;
    document.getElementById("horas").value = trabajadores[i].Horas;
    document.getElementById("valor").value = trabajadores[i].Valor;
}

function limpiar(){
    document.getElementById("miForm").reset();
}

function mostrar(){

    var lista = document.getElementById("lista");
    lista.innerHTML="";
    
    for(var i=0; i<trabajadores.length; i++){
        var renglon = document.createElement("option");
        renglon.text = trabajadores[i].Id + "  "+
                        trabajadores[i].Nombre + "  " +
                        trabajadores[i].Apellido + "  " +
                        trabajadores[i].Paga + "  " +
                        trabajadores[i].Saldo + "  " +
                        trabajadores[i].Horas + "  " +
                        trabajadores[i].Valor;
        lista.add(renglon);
    }
}

function mostrarSal(){

document.getElementById('saldo').style.display= 'block'
document.getElementById('horas').style.display= 'none'
document.getElementById('valor').style.display= 'none'
}

function mostrarJor(){
document.getElementById('horas').style.display= 'block'
document.getElementById('valor').style.display= 'block'
document.getElementById('saldo').style.display= 'none'
}




</script>
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho agregues el mensaje de error exacto que obtienes

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo HTML y el error que te marca en consola

Comment: Saludos. Le sugiero incluir el mensaje de error que se le presenta; así mismo, como finalizar como corresponde cada sentencia, en las funciones que indicas esta supuestamente el error no tiene el punto y coma ";" para finalizar cada línea. Así mismo, para mejor guía u orientación verifica que el código que pones sea el mismo que tienes donde falla.